# bluetooth file transfer using 32feet and c#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am trying to transfer the file to another device using bluetooth and [32feet.net](http://www.32feet.net) and c#. When I am trying to connect the other device I want to show an alert in the client device.

How do I do this?

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

1. what kind of alert/message?
2. make sure the blue tooth devices have been switched on, and connected, and authenticated.
3. did you pass the wrong device address?

I use the following code, it's working fine:

```
var file = @"C:\foo.JPG";
var uri = new Uri("obex://" + "REMOTE_DEVICE_ADDRESS_HERE" + "/" + file);
var request = new ObexWebRequest(uri);
request.ReadFile(file);
var response = (ObexWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
//check response.StatusCode
response.Close();
```